# How to pass integer variables using a self.redirect()

Tags: google-app-engine

i'm trying to pass an integer to a new page, for some reason the integer is not getting passed.

i'm passing index and edit_prop to edit_property and using get() to fetch the variables

view_property.py

```
    index = self.request.get('index')
    edit_prop = self.request.get('edit_prop')
    self.redirect('/edit_property?index' + index + '&edit_prop' + edit_prop)
```

edit_property.py

```
index = int(self.request.get('index'))
edit_prop = self.request.get('edit_prop')
```

invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
Traceback (most recent call last):enter code here

Answer (score 0):

Flask expects to get only [Response objects](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#about-responses). The parameter you want to pass is automatically converted into a Response object with a string as response body. I do not think that it is possible to pass integer values as they cannot be converted into responses. As a suggestion you can pass it as a String and process it later, from the route you want to use.